# If an app holds a partial wake lock and the phone is woken up, do other processes get access to the CPU too?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock, powermanager

It's been a longtime assumption of mine that when a `WakeLock` is held the device's CPU is fair game for all running processes. Does this assumption hold?

As an example, suppose processes A, B, and C exist. The phone has been asleep for 4 hours and none of these processes have been able to do work. Suddenly, process A acquires a `WakeLock` via an `AlarmManager` and holds it for 3 minutes. Do B and C get to do their work, too, during that 3 minute period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this assumption hold?

Yes.

> Do B and C get to do their work, too, during that 3 minute period?

Yes. In fact, this is specifically how things like `SyncManager` work, and specifically why Android 4.4 made it difficult for you to do an exact `AlarmManager` schedule. In the case of `AlarmManager`, the desire for inexact schedules allows Android to wake up the device once and do a bunch of work, rather than having to wake the device up lots of separate times.